# marklogic need advise for approach to aggregate documents

Tags: aggregate-functions, aggregate, marklogic

Hi MarkLogicians out there,

SEE BELOW FOR EDIT

I have the following challenge:
I have soci demographic zip code data, from a flat relational table.
According to good practice I have created one document per row. The doc(row) holds roughly 400 values structured in 7 categories of 40 variables, for each variable there are 4 to 7 segments.

```
<doc  id=1011AB >
 <cat>
   <var>
      <seg>
          25
      </seg>
   </var>
 </cat>
</doc>
```

There are 500.000 documents like these, we need to aggregate the 6 digit level to a higher zipcode level(4 digits) around 40.000 documents.

We have working code for aggregating one segment per document. Now I am looking for a solution to aggregate the 6 digit level to the 4 digit level. The aggregation basically is a calculation of weighted averages.

My question:
Is there an elegant why to take a 6 digit level document as a template and fill it out or do i need to build the 4 digit level doc from scratch?

===============  EDIT  ===================

ok so now I have a map in which we created a joined key like

```
<map:map xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<map:entry key="Consumententypes (sub):::Type 6, gezin met jongste kind 6+::: gezin met jongste kind 6+">
<map:value xsi:type="xs:double">
0
</map:value>
</map:entry>
<map:entry key="Woning:::Woontype:::De Veelbelovende Starter">
<map:value xsi:type="xs:double">
7.48
</map:value>
</map:entry>
```

with a corresponding value per key.

I want to recreate the doc based on decomposing the key
"category:::variable:::segment" to the structure above and add the map:value as an element value.

Question: What is the best way to build the document? Do I create a node, fill it with elelments and then instert it in ML or do I make an empty doc and add stuff as I go along (seems not so fast)

hugo

Comment: Not sure I follow your problem. More detail and/or an example might help...

Answer (score 0):

For a single-threaded approach, I would start by creating a map where the keys are six-digit codes and the values are the segments. You might be able to do this using http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:value-co-occurrences with the `map` option. Depending on the details that might mean one `cts:value-co-occurrences` call per category or variable or segment. I'm being vague because I don't see how those fit together in your use-case.

Once you have your six-digit map(s), use them to build four-digit map(s). That means looping through the six-digit keys and pushing new values into the four-digit map(s). Then you're ready to serialize the four-digit map(s) to new XML documents. That should be easy if the structure of your four-digit map entries is close to the final XML format. Write a simple XQuery function that takes a four-digit map and a code, and inserts the new document.

You might also think about concurrency using the Task Server. You could read all the six-digit codes from a lexicon, starting tasks that each process the six-digit codes corresponding to N four-digit codes. Done correctly that should be faster than one giant map. It's important to avoid any overlap in four-digit codes between the tasks, so that you don't have lock contention when inserting the new four-digit documents.

Comment: thx for your response, so a map is a key value store object right? is there a way to preserve the structure of the 6ppc object in a map? like a map of maps or something similar? remember i need to keep which category and which variabele a segment belongs to, so only building a map on segment looses the former right?

Comment: That's up to you. A map key is a string, but the value is item()* per http://docs.marklogic.com/map:put